# How to sample from $\{1, 2, ..., K\}$ for $n$ random variables, each with different mass functions, in R?

Tags: r, markov-chain-montecarlo

In R, I have an $N \times K$ matrix $P$ where the $i$'th row of $P$ corresponds to a distribution on $\{1, ..., K\}$. Essentially, I need to sample from each row efficiently. A naive implementation is:

```
X = rep(0, N);
for(i in 1:N){
    X[i] = sample(1:K, 1, prob = P[i, ]);
}
```

This is much too slow. In principle I could move this to C but I'm sure there must be an existing way of doing this. I would like something in the spirit of the following code (which does not work):

```
X = sample(1:K, N, replace = TRUE, prob = P)
```

**EDIT:** For motivation, take $N = 10000$ and $K = 100$. I have $P_1, ..., P_{5000}$ matrices all $N \times K$ and I need to sample a vector from each of them.

Comment: So you want a sample of size 1 from the probability distribution of each row?

Comment: @cardinal That is correct.

Comment: I would be interested to know what problem size you are considering. (That is, what is a typical value of $N$ and $K$ in your case?)

Comment: $K$ is $100$ for all intents and purposes. $N$ is sitting around $10000$. This process is being looped over anywhere from $5000$ to $20000$ times.

Comment: Do the samples need to be independent between rows? :-)

Comment: @whuber Yes; what I put in my naive implementation is exactly what needs to be implemented.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**We can do this in a couple of simple ways**. The first is easy to code, easy to understand and reasonably fast. The second is a little trickier, but *much* more efficient for this size of problem than the first method or other approaches mentioned here.

**Method 1**: Quick and dirty.

To get a single observation from the probability distribution of each row, we can simply do the following.

```
# Q is the cumulative distribution of each row.
Q <- t(apply(P,1,cumsum))

# Get a sample with one observation from the distribution of each row.
X <- rowSums(runif(N) > Q) + 1
```

This produces the cumulative distribution of each row of $P$ and then samples one observation from each distribution. Notice that if we can *reuse* $P$ then we can calculate $Q$ once and store it for later use. However, the question needs something that works for a different $P$ at each iteration.

If you need multiple ($n$) observations from each row, then replace the last line with the following one.

```
# Returns an N x n matrix
X <- replicate(n, rowSums(runif(N) > Q)+1)
```

This is really not an extremely efficient way in general to do this, but it *does* take good advantage of `R` vectorization capabilities, which is usually the primary determinant of execution speed. It is also straightforward to understand.

**Method 2**: Concatenating the cdfs.

Suppose we had a function that took two vectors, the second of which was sorted in monotonically nondecreasing order and found the index in the second vector of the greatest lower bound of each element in the first. Then, we could use this function and a slick trick: Just create the cumulative sum of the cdfs of all the rows. This gives a monotonically increasing vector with elements in the range $[0,N]$.

Here is the code.

```
i <- 0:(N-1)

# Cumulative function of the cdfs of each row of P.
Q <- cumsum(t(P))

# Find the interval and then back adjust
findInterval(runif(N)+i, Q)-i*K+1
```

Notice what the last line does, it creates random variables distributed in $(0,1), (1,2), \dots, (N-1,N)$ and then calls `findInterval` to find the index of the greatest lower bound of each entry. So, this tells us that the first element of `runif(N)+i` will be found between index 1 and index $K$, the second will be found between index $K+1$ and $2K$, etc, each according to the distribution of the corresponding row of $P$. Then we need to back transform to get each of the indices back in the range $\{1,\ldots,K\}$.

Because `findInterval` is fast both algorithmically and implementation-wise, this method turns out to be *extremely* efficient.

**A benchmark**

On my old laptop (MacBook Pro, 2.66 GHz, 8GB RAM), I tried this with $N = 10000$ and $K = 100$ and generating 5000 samples of size $N$, exactly as suggested in the updated question, for a total of 50 million random variates.

The code for **Method 1** took almost exactly 15 minutes to execute, or about 55K random variates per second. The code for **Method 2** took about **four and a half minutes** to execute, or about 183K random variates per second.

Here is the code for the sake of reproducibility. (Note that, as indicated in a comment, $Q$ is recalculated for each of the 5000 iterations to simulate the OP's situation.)

```
# Benchmark code
N <- 10000
K <- 100

set.seed(17)
P <- matrix(runif(N*K),N,K)
P <- P / rowSums(P)

method.one <- function(P)
{
    Q <- t(apply(P,1,cumsum))
    X <- rowSums(runif(nrow(P)) > Q) + 1
}

method.two <- function(P)
{
    n <- nrow(P)
    i <- 0:(n-1)
    Q <- cumsum(t(P))
    findInterval(runif(n)+i, Q)-i*ncol(P)+1
}
```

Here is the output.

```
# Method 1: Timing
> system.time(replicate(5e3, method.one(P)))
   user  system elapsed 
691.693 195.812 899.246 

# Method 2: Timing
> system.time(replicate(5e3, method.two(P)))
   user  system elapsed 
182.325  82.430 273.021
```

**Postscript**: By looking at the code for `findInterval`, we can see that it does some checks on the input to see if there are `NA` entries or if the second argument is not sorted. Hence, if we wanted to squeeze more performance out of this, we could create our own modified version of `findInterval` which strips out these checks which are unnecessary in our case.

Comment: I'll give this a shot. I think this is too slow because of the use of "apply" which I think is hiding a loop within R. The order of magnitude of $N$ and $K$ are about right in your example, but it is sitting inside of an MCMC implementation.

Comment: The code above *does* assume that all $P_{ij} > 0$ (strict).

Comment: @guy: $Q$ only needs to be calculated *once* at the beginning and stored.

Comment: Unfortunately $P$ varies over each iteration.

Comment: Does P change arbitrarily?  If only a small number of things change per iteration, maybe you can salvage the approach.  Also, it might help to back up and talk about the application.  The fastest work is the work you never do.

Comment: @rrenaud: I have attempted to provide a fairly simple general-purpose answer independent of the OP's problem, in part, because this answer was posted when the details of the question were a little more sparse. At any rate, the code is still quite fast and, of course, much faster if $P$ is fixed.

Comment: Apologies for the details being sparse, although I think the original question reflects the problem adequately if you require the solution to be efficient for $N$ very large (say on the order of $10^7$). @rrenaud $P$ changes fairly arbitrarily. The context is involved and would probably be distracting, but I don't think I'm trying to do anything absurd.

Comment: No apology necessary, @guy. I was just trying to briefly explain the rationale behind my answer to rrenaud. I'm not sure if you application would provide for producing the cumulative distribution directly, instead of the pmf, but if so, that would speed things up tremendously.

Comment: If I'm returning X in the code provided, should I take X = ncol(P) + 1 - rowSums(runif(nrow(P)) <= Q)?

Comment: Also, in response to the possibility of my application providing $Q$ directly, this unfortunately is not possible. I suppose though that, at the very least, if speed really is an issue it reduces the problem to using .C to get the cumsum of each row, which is only a little inconvenient. Still hoping that someone already has written compiled code to do this though. I really would have thought it would be in base R since you can do things like dnorm(vector, matrix, matrix) and get what you would hope to get.

Comment: @guy: You'd just return $X$. :)

Comment: Are you sure? When I implemented it that way I get values of 100 when I should get 1 (red flags went off for me because most of the mass is in the first few columns of each $P$ matrix).

Comment: @guy: Sorry; I had the inequality flipped. I'll correct it. Thanks for checking that. :)

Comment: @guy: I've added a second, much faster method for your consideration.

Comment: @rrenaud: Ping. See if you like the second method better. It's still a bit raw, but also much more efficient. :)

Comment: Method 2 is quite clever. Thanks :) I think that works well enough at this stage of my work.

Comment: Excellent!! (+1) Indeed, you might gain a little by calling directly .C("find_interv_vec", xt = as.double(Q), n = length(Q), x = as.double(runif(n)+1), nx = n, FALSE, FALSE, n, DUP = FALSE, NAOK = TRUE, PACKAGE = "base") but I guess that to go faster you'll need to go into C. This version has ho extra calculation and not too many function calls!

Answer (score 6):

A `for` loop may be terribly slow in `R`. How about this simple vectorization with `sapply`?

```
n <- 10000
k <- 200

S <- 1:k
p <- matrix(rep(1 / k, n * k), nrow = n, ncol = k)
x <- numeric(n)

x <- sapply(1:n, function(i) sample(S, 1, prob = p[i,]))
```

Of course, this uniform p is just for testing.

Comment: I changed to $k = 100$ to make the comparison more fair and replicated the last two lines 500 times. It ran in 100 seconds on my laptop, or about 10/9 of the time of the code in the other answer. That's fairly comparable. The *interesting* thing is that your code uses almost exclusively "user" time, while the one in my answer uses a much greater proportion of "system" time. I'm not sure at the moment why that is. Also, I've not sure what, if any, effect of simulating using a uniform in your case might have.

Comment: Replicating the penultimate line will make R allocate memory for x over and over, and I believe that's is very slow. May you try to replicate just the last line, cardinal? This "user" against "system" time thing is funny.

Comment: I've tried with the same $P$ as in my code. I get 121 seconds for 500 iterations. So, having a uniform does seem to matter a bit. At any rate, I'm actually a little surprised that this method is as competitive as it is. (+1)

Comment: Funny enough, removing that line had no effect on the timing. A tad surprising.

Comment: OMG, R is behaviour is sometimes unpredictable...

Comment: (+1, long ago). Sometimes we ignore the most straightforward ways in languages like R and MATLAB due to folklore or experience with them not working well. Sometimes, like this one, they turn out to be surprisingly competitive.